# How to have 2 textboxes as mutually exclusive in an html form?

Tags: html, django

I would like to have 2 mutually exclusive fields.

One will be a FileField and other TextBoxField.

Is there a ready html form I can get my hands on to.

I have searched the web and couldnt find any.

Oh I am a little sorry..

I meant that I wanted to do this via Django Templates

Answer (score 0):

You can make an onInput event listener and handle it using javascript, so that if the user types in one field it empties the other.

For example:

```
<form>
    <label for="first">Fill This:</label>
    <input type="text" name="first" id="first" oninput="run('first')"><br><br>
    <label for="second">Or This:</label>
    <input type="text" name="second" id="second" oninput="run('second')"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
    function run(activeField) {
        if (activeField == 'first') {
            const second = document.querySelector('#second')
            second.value = ''
        } else {
            const first = document.querySelector('#first')
            first.value = ''
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Your textbox, you can use this:

```
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Please enter your name">
```

And for your files:

```
<input type="file" name="fileName">
```

But for file name it needs to be encrypted. HTML won't let you submit a form with a file. But you can override this in the form attr, like this:

```
<form action="dirToForm.py" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>
```